Detect active channel used in a lora network
I am trying for quite some days now to detect which channel was used for a transmitted LoRaWAN frame.
For those who are not familiar with lora: LoRa makes use of the CSS modulation technique, which is also my guess why e.g. a Xlating fir filter (which is apparently a quite common solution for channel detection) is not really helpful. But to be honest I am not 100% sure if I had the right configuration.
I also tried 2 different brute force approaches.
1. approach

set the bandwidth of my hackrf to the channel bandwidth
use low pass
loop through each channel by changing the center frequency of the hackrf and check for an active signal

I think the problem here was that this approach is too slow, changing the center frequency of the hackrf probably takes some time.
2. approach

set the bandwidth of the hackrf to a wider spectrum
create multiple layers of filters in a kind of "binary search tree" pattern - upshift and downshifting the original signal, use a low pass filter, check which of the two signals is active and repeat those steps until we reached the last layer. (3 layers should be sufficient for my purpose).

None of this really worked out, also I am not sure if my approaches are completely gibberish and jibber-jabber. Any help or ideas would be very welcome. Thanks.

you're thinking very serially here – why not simply do a bandpass filter for each potential channel and run them all at once, on the same input signal? One can computationally optimize that, but in a first step: when your problem calls for a filter bank, do a filter bank.

Other than that, I'm not sure I'd use a classical filter followed by energy detection to detect a low-power wide area signal – that is bound to be close to, or even below, noise floor! Lora's signal structure really stems from a need to detect it easily. There's existing literature on Lora reception, I'd recommend you check ieeexplore and the usual web search engines on that!

Thank you! The filter bank is the solution I was looking for. I was not aware that this is common pattern, since I thought it would take too much resources (but adapting the transition width of the filters helps a lot).
I still wonder how you would deal with signals which have a higher bandwidth compared to the channel size (and still be able to receive the 125 KHz signals), but for now this solution is sufficient.

CSS is "Chirp Spread Spectrum" so you need to dechirp the waveform first (multiply with a complex conjugate locally generated frequency chirp) and then demodulate the waveform using M-ary Frequency Shift Keying. This write-up by Matthew Knight and Balint Seeber goes into specific details on demodulating LoRa specifically:
https://pubs.gnuradio.org/index.php/grcon/article/download/8/7/

Sounds like this is the (better) way to go! I discovered the git repo you are referring to, sadly I had trouble installing it, why I used gr_lora_sdr (https://github.com/tapparelj/gr-lora_sdr) instead, which requires you to specify the edges of the signal. Still I appreciate your answer, thanks for pointing out the ideal solution!
